# how to put scrollbars around a raphael based canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, raphael

I think it's a classical question : considering a big canvas in a web page, how can I put it in a small DIV with scrollbars around?
I found many such questions about this in stack overflow, but, as I I'm a newbie, I can't reproduce the examples in my IDE.

here are some answers:
-[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640744/need-a-scroll-around-raphael-canvas)

-[and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250406/adding-a-scroll-bar-to-the-raphael-canvas)

here is a non-working code of mine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv="content-type">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function graphiques(){

        var paper = Raphael('holder', 800, '100%');
        // add your graphics to the paper object here
        var rect=paper.rect(50,50,70,20,5).attr("fill":"#cc3");
        var height = $(paper.canvas).outerHeight();
        paper.setSize(800, height);
        $(paper.canvas).parent().height("100px");
  }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="graphiques();">
      <div id="holder" style="overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:auto;">
      <script>graphiques();</script>
      </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

my question is : what change do I need to make in order to make it work?
and if my code goes in a wrong direction, what is the correct method (with code please I'm net an advanced javascript user!)

thanks

olivier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Rapha�l tutorial - Getting Started - Example 1</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="raphael-min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  #paper1{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="paper1"></div>
<!-- the html element where to put the paper -->
<!-- a script that create's a paper and a rectangle -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var paper = Raphael("paper1", 500,500);

var rect1 = paper.rect(20,30,500,500).attr({fill: "orange"});

</script>
```